# How to populate a fragment with an entity from a Room Database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-mvvm

On navigation to a fragment I'm passing an ID of a Room DB entity. I'm now trying to set the text of a textview to an attribute of this entity.

This is what I'm currently trying, but it doesn't seem to work:

I have a ViewModel called editPlanViewModel in my Fragment. This is the ViewModel:

```
class EditPlanViewModel(
private val trainingPlanKey: Long = 0L,
val database: TrainingPlannerDatabaseDao) : ViewModel() {

private val viewModelJob = Job()
private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

private val _plan = MutableLiveData<TrainingPlan>()
val plan: LiveData<TrainingPlan>
    get() = _plan

init {
    uiScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Before get")
            _plan.value = database.get(trainingPlanKey) ?: return@withContext
            Log.d("DEBUG", "After get")
        }
    }
}

override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    viewModelJob.cancel()
}
```

In TrainingPlannerDatabaseDao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM training_plan_table WHERE planId = :key")
fun get(key: Long): TrainingPlan?
```

The plan LiveData should be changed so in my Fragment I set up an observer:

```
editPlanViewModel.plan.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { plan ->
    Log.d("DEBUG", "In observer")
    if (plan != null) {
        binding.planName.text = plan.name
    }
})
```

It seems that the observer is never triggered. I added three logs, but only the "Before get" is triggered.

Does anyone know why the observer is not triggered or have another way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not reaching past this line with no exceptions:

```
_plan.value = database.get(trainingPlanKey) ?: return@withContext
```

then it can only be that `database.get(trainingPlanKey)` was null and everything is working as intended.

Comment: I was indeed passing my key incorrectly so my query was returning null. Why is it that no code below the query runs when the query fails?

Comment: Because of the `?: return` you added, this essentially means return if the left hand side is `null`! https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator